# Custom post type - related products

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've made a custom post type "product" on my Wordpress site. The detail page of a product is single-product.php which shows everything about the product perfectly.

All the product will be categorized in the following structure:

1. Toegangscontroles

   1. Elektronische sloten
   2. Wandlezers
   3. Software
   4. ...
2. Overige producten

   1. Sleutelkaarten
   2. Kluizen
   3. ...

I have two test products on my website. Both products have the category "Electronische sloten". Which is a child category of "Toegangscontroles".

[image: Category]

I want to show related products on single-product.php This related product cannot be the current product itself and must be under the same parent category. So in this case, a product with child category "Toegangscontroles" must show 5 random related products from the child categories from parent "Toegangscontroles".

This is my code now:

```
<?php
    $related = get_posts( array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
        'numberposts' => 5, 
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );

    if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();    
 ?>
```

When I go the product A, I see product B under related products, but when I go the the product B page, I don't see product A. Tough they have exactly the same category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but you can try

```
$related = get_posts( array( 
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'tax_query' => array( array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy_name, array('fields' => 'ids'))        
  ) ),
  'numberposts' => 5, 
  'exclude' => array($post->ID)
) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it doesn't work. Your code gives the other posts. I have two products with child category "Elektronische sloten" from parent "Toegangscontroles" and 1 product from child category "Sleutelkaarten" from parent "Overige producten".

When I'm at the single-product.php page it still shows products from the other parent category. I only want to see products from the same parent category.

Comment: Have tested, and it's working. Use var_dump(wp_get_post_categories($post->ID)) to output and check which categories IDs do you collect, them compare them to which you SHOULD receive. Also check $post->ID variable to match the currect product. Also do you have a category or if it's a custom taxonomy?

Comment: It is a custom taxonomy

Comment: You have to use wp_get_post_terms() in this case instead of wp_get_post_categories() - updated an answer

Comment: Thanks for this! but I'm getting an syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
And where does $taxonomy_name get a value ?

Comment: $taxonomy_name is your custom taxonomy name, which was used when registering the taxonomy. You can check it in the dashboard (when you edit the taxonomy, it's name is shown in the URL). Sorry for the error '=' should be '=>'

Comment: Okay the error is gone and I see related products. But it still displays products from the other parent category.

For example: I'm on the single page of a product with child term "Kluizen" and it's parent term "Overige producten". But I still see related products from the parent category "Toegangscontroles".

Comment: Can you use var_dump(wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy_name, array('fields' => 'names'))) and add the output to your question?

Comment: This is the result of var_dump
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Kluizen" [1]=> string(17) "Overige producten" }

Comment: And this can be a stupid suggestion, but check products not to belong to both categories))

Comment: So the first string "Kluizen" is a child of "Overige producten".

Comment: The query is correct, is gets only products which have these categories

Comment: The result isn't correct. Because on the detail page of product "Safe locker". This product has the child term "Kluizen" under parent term "Overige producten". But this product is at this moment the only product under the term "Overige producten".

So the result should be no related products for this one.

Comment: Oh, sorry bro. The tax_query shall be a multidimensional array

Comment: Fixed that one :D

Comment: Yes, works like a charm ! Thank you for your time and patience :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code i think it will work.

```
$related = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID )
    )
);

if( $related->have_posts() ) { 
    while( $related->have_posts() ) { 
        $related->the_post(); ?>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```